# Object literal - adding items

Tags: javascript

I have this in my code:-

```
var chartOptions = {
      series: {
               bars: { show: true }
              }
};
```

Is there a way I could add another item to the chartOptions object through code so that it was added an item to the series part, like this:-

```
series: {
    bars: {show: true, fillColor="Red"}
}
```

How would I go about doing this?  I was expecting something like:-

```
chartOptions["series"]["bars"]["fillColor"] = "Red"
```

But that doesn't work.  I'm pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: `chartOptions["series"]["bars"]["fillColor"] = "Red"` should work, it's more convenient to write and read it as `chartOptions.series.bars.fillColor = "Red";` though.

Comment: Why do you think that your attempt didn't work?  It certainly should.

Comment: Are you looking to mimic [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it inline by using `:` instead of `=`

```
series: {
    bars: {show: true, fillColor: "Red"}
}
```

Or you can add it in code using [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or with JavaScript:

```
chartOptions.series.bars.fillColor = "Red";
```

Your code `chartOptions["series"]["bars"]["fillColor"] = "Red"` should also work but it is the notation when dealing with arrays. The dot notation is usually used when dealing with objects. Both notations are mostly interchangeable though.

Comment: I think the `=` typo is not in actual code, but only in where he's trying to show what he want the resulting object to look like.

Comment: `chartOptions["series"]["bars"]["fillColor"] = "Red";` works, what are you trying to tell him, to use jquery?

Comment: I'm not telling him to do anything, I provide options: 1) inline. 2) jQuery.extend. 3) Square brackets notation (his own solution) or 4) Dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) {
        destination[property] = source[property];
    }

    return destination;
}

var chartOptions = {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true
        }
    }
};

Object.extend(chartOptions.series.bars, {
    fillColor: "Red"
});

console.log(chartOptions);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5KMfy/4/

I wrote 2 working examples, with and without jQuery, hope this helps.